# Remove slide number text from top of ng carousal

Tags: css, angular-ui-bootstrap, ng-bootstrap

I am using this carousal from ng-bootstrap :

```
<ngb-carousel [showNavigationArrows]="showNavigationArrows" [showNavigationIndicators]="showNavigationIndicators">
    <ng-template ngbSlide>
      <div class="picsum-img-wrapper">
        <img src="assets\fsfhjllz_vegetables-banner.png" class="mh-100" style="width: 100%; height: 30vh; object-fit:cover;">
      </div>
    </ng-template>
  
    <ng-template ngbSlide>
      <div class="picsum-img-wrapper">
        <img src="assets\vh9oeys6_fruit-banner.png" class="mh-100" style="width: 100%; height: 30vh; object-fit: cover;">
      </div>
    </ng-template>
</ngb-carousel>
```

And it shows this text on top of image like:: slide 1 of 2 .

How do I remove this text and only show image.
It is showing up as this when inspected in browser::

```
<div role="tabpanel" class="carousel-item" id="slide-ngb-slide-1">
<span class="sr-only"> Slide 2 of 2 </span>                      // this one
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the source code of this peace:

```
<span class="sr-only" i18n="Currently selected slide number read by screen reader@@ngb.carousel.slide-number">
  Slide {{i + 1}} of {{c}}
</span>
```

I see 2 possibilities to hide this text:

1. add the CSS to hide `.carousel-inner .sr-only` to hide this element, eg

```css
.carousel-inner .sr-only {
   display: none;
}
```

2. set the value of the translation key `ngb.carousel.slide-number` to an empty string. [Guidelines on internatiolization](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/guides/i18n).

Comment: This solution is not working for me.

Comment: The above css should be added in global styles.

Comment: Sounds like one needs to learn what is view encapsulation in Angular (:
https://angular.io/guide/view-encapsulation

Answer (score 0):

With ngbootstrap 15.1 and bootstrap 5, the `<span>` that shows the slide information, e.g. "Slide 2 of 2", now carries the css class `visually-hidden`.

If you are using Bootstrap with SCSS and did not import the whole of bootstrap via `@import "/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";`, but instead import only what you need, then you will find the css class inside `helpers/_visually-hidden`:
`@import "bootstrap/scss/helpers/_visually-hidden";`

Bootstrap documentation: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/helpers/visually-hidden/

Answer (score 0):

Using  ViewEncapsulation, this can be achieved.
Add the below style to component.css file

```
.visually-hidden {
    display: none;
 }
```

or

```
 .carousel-inner span {
    display: none;
 }
```

Also add,
encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None in @Component decorator in component.ts file

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```