# Angular Bootstrap Carousel-> Remove slide number text from top of ng carousal

Tags: angular, carousel, angular-bootstrap

I am using Angular Bootstrap Carousel to run the image slides on my home page, it is always showing text as: "Slide 1 of 4".

[image]

I have tried many thing but could not remove it. Similar question is already asked but its solution didn't worked for me:
[Remove slide number text from top of ng carousal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68163223/remove-slide-number-text-from-top-of-ng-carousal)

```html
 <div>
    <!-- <img src="../../assets/images/background.png" class="bgimage"/> -->
    <ngb-carousel *ngIf="images" [showNavigationArrows]="showNavigationArrows" [showNavigationIndicators]="showNavigationIndicators">

      <ng-template ngbSlide *ngFor="let image of images">
        <div class="picsum-img-wrapper">
          <img [src]="image" alt="Random slide" class="d-block w-100" style="height: 450px">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h3>No mouse navigation</h3>
          <p>This carousel hides navigation arrows and indicators.</p>
        </div>
      </ng-template>
    </ngb-carousel>
  </div>
```

Please help.

Comment: Might have better luck getting help with this if you reproduce the issue on StackBlitz

Comment: I just want to hide the slide number appearing in Angular-bootstrap-carousel.  Angular-version: 10.1.5, Bootstrap version: 5.1.3

Answer (score 0):

Add to style.css

```
.visually-hidden, .visually-hidden-focusable:not(:focus):not(:focus-within) {
position: absolute !important;
width: 1px !important;
height: 1px !important;
padding: 0 !important;
margin: -1px !important;
overflow: hidden !important;
clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0) !important;
white-space: nowrap !important;
border: 0 !important; 
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).